# How to upload a file with ajax and move it with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, security, extjs

I'm using javascript to get the filepath but it returns *C:\fakepat\ **fileName***, then I replace the fakepath to get the filename only. Then ajax to php. And execute this line:

```
copy("filename", $targetPath);
```

It returns this error **no directory or file**.

Comment: Has the file been uploaded via PHP? You should be copying it from the temp directory.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Sounds like you are trying to build a file upload, do you?

Comment: Yes, I want to build my upload file in server directory. :)

Answer (score 2):

PHP is executed on server-side, therefor it has no access to your client-side file.

To transmit the file from client to server using ajax I recommend wrapping a form around your upload-button. After submitting the XHR you can access the file in PHP via the $_FILES variable and move it where ever you want:

**HTML**

```
<form>
   <input type="file" id="upload" onchange="javascript:uploadFile()" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function uploadFile() {
    var formData = new FormData();  // using XMLHttpRequest2
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    formData.append("uploadfile", file);
    request.send(formData);
}
```

**PHP**

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    // upload succeeded
} else {
    // upload failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in ajax you can write this

```
var form_data = new FormData();
         var file_data1 = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
        form_data.append('file', file_data1);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/addEdi.php', // point to server-side PHP script
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (php_script_response) {
            $('#res').html(php_script_response);
             }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

@Toltis Because of the fakepath, you should upload via javascript.

This it the html:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="upload(event)" />
<img src="" id="img" />
<textbox id="hidden_box" name="hidden_box" style="visibility: hidden;"></textbox>
```

Then the Js:

```
function upload(e) {
    var input_file = document.getElementById('file');
    var hidden = document.getElementById('hidden_box');
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsDataURL(input_file.files[0]);
    fr.onloadend = function(e) {
        var img_tag = document.getElementById('img');
        dataUrl = e.target.result;
        img_tag = dataUrl
        hidden.innerHTML = dataUrl
    }
}
```

Then you can target the contents of the hidden box in php. Break it on the (,) and then decode the remaining string - base64_decode - and then save it to a file.

The real file name, you already know how to get it.